# How to fix pointer event issue in Chrome 55+ without upgrade to newer version

Tags: google-chrome, sapui5

We are using UI5 library version 1.36.12 in our Web app but due to chrome update some controls like IconTabBar, MulticomboBox are not working properly due to pointer events not disabled by default in the latest versions of Chrome.

One solution to this problem is to upgrade to version 1.38.14 but we are running in a tight schedule and we have to make many changes if we update the library.

One solution I tried is adding the [fix](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/08df0bd223bc0617a591fe0cb80c2dc8fd24ce96) in sap.ui.core.js file in current library jar files. But it is still not working. Should I have to rebuild sap.ui.core.js file and if yes how should I do that?

Please don't suggest to manually deactivate functionality in chrome through `chrome://flags/#enable-pointer-events` as client is not approving for that. Please suggest me a way to solve this issue **without upgrading the library**.

Comment: Related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1265#issuecomment-268245606

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current UI5 version you can load your own Device object beforehand and UI5 will use it. I assume that this works in your version as well.

UPDATE: My proposal to reset the value later cannot work as it is used in the bootstrap mechanism. Therefore I removed this. Then the last resort is to use the approach mentioned by [codeworrior](https://github.com/codeworrior) on [GitHub](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1265#issuecomment-268245606):

Before you bootstrap UI5 add a script tag and do the following:

```
if (/chrome/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
   delete window.PointerEvent;
}
```

In this case pointer support is set to false.

Comment: Hi @matbtt, Thanks for the suggestion but its not working when i am trying override the value in init event. Is there any other way to solve this issue

Comment: I checked it cannot work. Please try the approach to delete window.PointerEvent.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Only thing that works is using Chrome flag, which of course is not good enough.